# Why did Han seem unhappy that Rey bypassed the compressor?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

Why did Han seem unhappy that Rey bypassed the compressor?

[image]

They both agreed that it was a bad addition to the Falcon.

Comment: Are you referring to the scene where he mucks up the ignition sequence or the scene (pictured above) where she removes the compressor unit completely?

Comment: @Valorum I was talking about the one above where he goes "What did you do?" and she goes "I bypassed the compressor!". But based on your correct answer it seems you figured it out :)

Comment: It's less clear from the novels because the scene doesn't happen in any of the three. In the books they take off and then just go straight to hyperspeed.

Comment: The way I read the scene, he wasn't unhappy that she bypassed the compressor -- he was unhappy that she figured it out before he did.

Comment: He was probably unhappy because the main character in this Star Wars has all the powers of every other character put together, rendering him, and the others, quite obsolete

Comment: [Definitely **not** unhappy.](https://youtu.be/44H2_cu02P4?t=32s)

Comment: @Blazemonger Yes, I think you're right. That makes sense. So he was unhappy but for reasons related to his ego rather than the hyperdrive.

Comment: Han isn't unhappy. He's just what you'd expect from any man late in his life: looking grumpy no matter what he's doing or actually feels.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The [film script](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-The-Force-Awakens.html) indicates that he wasn't unhappy, just confused.

> **HAN:** *This hyperdrive blows there's gonna be pieces of us in three different systems.*
>
> Han at the controls when all the alarms STOP. Rey, satisfied, sits in
>   the co-pilot seat. **Han is confused.**
>
> **HAN** (CONT'D): *What'd you do?*
>
> **REY:** *I by-passed the compressor.*
>
> **He looks at her.** A little, appreciative laugh. Han exits, walking past
>   BB-8.

Comment: Maybe true, but that's a shortcoming of the script.  Han *would* be unhappy, for the reasons @dmoonfire suggests, and Ford (who has always apparently had a better sense for the character than the scriptwriters) certainly played him as unhappy.

Comment: @periatabreatta - I think that's just how Harrison Ford looks.

Comment: I wonder if Harrison Ford took some minor liberty with the script in this scene. Did he go "Huh." or "Hmm."? I'm not sure how you'd type that noise he made.

Comment: Being Han, he is not going to outright congratulate someone, or even be "happy" about it. It seems to me he was impressed that she did that, but of course too prideful to admit he didn't think about that solution.

Comment: The Han Solo Adventures get into Han and Chewies relationship with the Falcon. It is their home, their source of income, and their biggest tangible asset. Han is only comfortable letting a few others work on it like the mechanic named in the Han Solo Adventures (Doc and Jessa I think). This book wasn't a core part of the old expanded universe, but it does build on the history that Han and Chewie have and how they treat the Falcon.

Comment: I always thought it came through clearly in the original trilogy - perhaps "Empire Strikes Back" if not "A New Hope". The Millennium Falcon is Han's "baby" - there was a short scene where Chewbacca is doing maintenance and Han gets upset over the way Chewie - his most trusted friend - was working. Now along comes Rey, someone he hardly knows, who starts tinkering.

Comment: How / where did you get a copy of the script, anyway (jw)? is it from http://www.imsdb.com? Is that a transcription or how do they get it? I'm just curious. I almost bought an autographed script on eBay once but then I decided that the sellers probably printed it and autographed it themselves.

Comment: @hack-r - The script was leaked a few days after the film was released. It was actually a "for your consideration" copy sent to the Academy. Evidently the writers were hoping to win an Oscar.

Answer (score 82):

When I saw that scene, I figured it was two things.

One was that a young thing was moving faster than him and matching him for skill with his ship, his baby. She basically had mastered the thing he spent a *long* time trying to recover. The Falcon was his thing and she handled it as well as him.

The other is that he was feeling pretty old; few people like having children (probably from his view) exceeding their skill.

A third is that maybe he was wishing it was Ben sitting there, being all excited about solving the problem.

Comment: I have to give the check mark to the script answer but this is also a very good answer, thank you

Comment: @Hack-R I don’t know that you do—Harrison Ford may very well have acted the way he did intentionally, for reasons much like these, whatever the script said, as part of his mastery of the character.

Comment: Good point. I wish I could mark both answers as correct. @Valorum what say you on this, good sir?

Comment: @Hack-R Isn't this just the age old in-universe vs out-of-universe debate? Well, not exactly, because Kryan postulates an alternative out-of-universe hypothesis, but it's just his conjecture whilst Valorum provides a solid out-of-universe answer.

Comment: @DavidMulder Well Mr. Moon Fire got a million upvotes and Mr. Valorum got the green checkmark so I figure both parties should be pretty happy!

Comment: I was not prepared for that last point. Right in the _feels_!

Comment: Wow, congratulations on a Populist badge so early in your SFF career!

Answer (score 17):

There's an answer here that references the script. However, the script doesn't address Harrison Ford's protrayal of the character. I'll say this:

Han wasn't unhappy - and he wasn't just confused - he was *impressed*.

In this movie, Han's archetype has changed slightly; he's still a smuggler, but he's feeling his years. Partly due to the character's age, and partly due to Harrison Ford's [Cool Old Guy](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/CoolOldGuy) status, Han comes across as a [Retired Badass](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/RetiredBadass). Rey continues to impress Han with her feats (such as fixing the hyperdrive issue) to the point that Han offers her a position aboard the Falcon (albeit with grudging respect, playing it cool up to the very end, the sneaky dog).

Essentially, Han's reaction is just that he's playing it cool. That's his meal ticket and it's an essential part of the character.

Here's the clip. The reference is around the 32-second mark, but the entire clip gives meaningful context: